# Point of tangency between two curves proof of method

Tags: calculus

Given two functions $f$ and $g$, both continuous and differentiable near $x=a$, with continuous derivatives near $x=a$. Then they have a point of tangency at $x=a$ if:

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-a}=0$$

Why is this true?

And, secondly, why implicates this that:

$f(a)=g(a)$ and $f'(a)=g'(a)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you. This is not a homework service.

Comment: What's the definition of "point of tangency" you are working with?

Answer (score 1):

Beware of examples like this $\begin{cases}f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}\\g(x)=\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}\end{cases}$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ynhl4dzemt

They satisfy the point of tangency and $f(1)=g(1)$ but there are other issues:

- $f'(1)$ and $g'(1)$ are not finite, but even though the limits are $\pm\infty$ with different sign.
- $f$ and $g$ do not have the same domain, therefore the quantity $\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-1}$ is undefined.

So you should impose restrictions on your functions $f,g$ to constraint the result to be true, because as is, it is not.

---

Under the conditions $f,g\in C^1([a-\delta,a+\delta])$ for some given $\delta>0$

The equation of the tangent line to $y=f(x)$ at $x=a$ are simply given by $y=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)$

Requesting that the two curves are tangent means that the $2$ tangent lines are the same geometrically (i.e. we ignore orientation), therefore touch at $(a,f(a))$ and have same slope $f'(a)$.

This is realized when $f(a)=g(a)$ and $f'(a)=g'(a)$

Now locally by Taylor expansion of $C^1$ functions $\begin{cases}f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+o(x-a)\\g(x)=g(a)+(x-a)g'(a)+o(x-a)\end{cases}$

And you get immediately $\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{x-a}=\dfrac{o(x-a)}{x-a}=o(1)\to 0$

Comment: +1 : Issues around the domain of each of the two functions never occurred to me.  As far as your other remark, I question the appropriateness.  The posted question asserted that if a condition is met, then there is a point of tangency, rather than *if and only if* there is a point of tangency.  Further, unless I am mistaken, implicit in the premise that each derivative exists (and is continuous) is the premise that each derivative is finite at the specified element in the domain.

Comment: At the time I answered, these requirements were not present I think. But anyway I agree the $C^1$ condition in a neighbourhood of $x=a$ and an overlap of $f,g$ in this neighbourhood should be enough. The finite derivatives avoid the case $y=\pm\sqrt[3]{x}$ which are vertical tangent with opposite sign. It is still possible with $\pm 0$ but in this case this is plain $0$.